# Issue starting React

Tags: reactjs, windows

I am running an ubuntu shell on windows and when i try to "npm start" I get this error. Anyone else having this issue?

```
Starting the development server...

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd.exe ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! awesome-project@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the awesome-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/tyronsamaroo/.npm/_logs/2019-09-07T19_46_59_272Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Windows?

You might not have the system path environment variable. Try to run this in your terminal, and then run the command again.

`export PATH=$PATH:C:\Windows\System32`

Comment: What does that actually do? Do you have a link you can share I can read about that? Also I tried something weird and it worked for now

Comment: In the project file I change the react-scripts to version 2.1.8 it was 3.1.1 before. I then also ran npm install to take care of the dependencies and it worked...